# Caching and searching through multiple SQL query results client-side in web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm building a page with a panel of dropdown controls loaded from multiple SQL queries. The content can change by the hour. The user selects one dropdown after another to pick their search criteria, then a database is queried and loads results into a table.

Now, the user wants each of the dropdowns to filter each other's content.

Example: If somebody chooses "Purchase Orders" in one dropdown, then a separate dropdown for all users who have access to the application would then change to be users who are allowed to edit purchase orders. There's 5 dropdowns in total, and each could alter the content of the other 4.

Currently, I am loading all dropdowns in the code behind. With this requirement change, there would have to be a partial postback to query the DBs to update the controls' content, and I think that would affect user experience. Instead I think it would be better, performance-wise, to handle all of this client-side. This would involve caching the content for the dropdowns at application startup, and then searching through those to load the filtered-down results with each dropdown change.

However **I have no idea how to even start implement this**, and that is where I need help. How I can get these drop down controls to work together with data loaded in the client? Or, alternatively, how can I keep partial postbacks responsive to the user?

Comment: The problem with this approach is it's not responsive to data changes. For example, adding or removing a user with purchase order permissions suddenly requires restarting the app, and requires clients to reload your entire large data set on every restart/change. Additionally, this pushes all that data into the client, where a knowledgable person could use it to run queries and see things they might not be supposed to see. The partial postbacks/ajax solution can be much more responsive than you think, without having these other problems. Either way, you need to think in terms of JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: dumb question but can you elaborate on what you mean by thinking in terms of javascript? My JS is weak.

Comment: Sure. You don't want to find yourself writing VB.Net or C# code to make DOM changes to an already-loaded HTML page. That's where your extra latency comes from. This overly simplifies it, but as much as possible you want to your VB.Net/C# code to send a fully-rendered HTML page to a client browser _**once**_. Then, user interactions with that page should be managed mainly via javascript (and a few `[WebMethod()]`s), until the user is finally ready to submit the contents and move to the next page.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Use Websocket (possibly SignalR) to update changed data in all clients. This mechanism is underutilized and it can create wonderful dynamism through partial real-time data updates.